# Rotating HTML canvas text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a rectangle with text labelled 150 along the edge

How do I rotate the text "150" to read as bottom to top. The below code makes 150 to look top to bottom along the edge.

The expected is above
[image]

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const x = 150;
const y = 150;
const w = 200;
const h = 150;

ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.fillRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
ctx.font = "12px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Rectangle", x + w / 2, y + h / 2);

ctx.fillText('200', x + w / 2, y + h - 5);
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x + w, y + h / 2);

ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);

ctx.fillText('150', 0, 0 + w - 5);
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perhaps ctx.setTransform somehow?

Comment: So you wish to rotate text to other direction?

Comment: Yes rotate text to 180, if I set to 180 it disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice negative translation & negative rotation.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const x = 150;
const y = 150;
const w = 200;
const h = 150;

ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
ctx.fillRect(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, w, h);
ctx.font = "12px Comic Sans MS";
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Rectangle", x + w / 2, y + h / 2);

ctx.fillText('200', x + w / 2, y + h - 5);
ctx.save();

ctx.translate(x - w, y + h / 2);
ctx.rotate(-90 * Math.PI / 180);

ctx.fillText('150', 0, w + 15); /* 15 is width of the text itself */
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```